# How to Hide a component in react native

Tags: react-native

Hi I have TextInput like this

[image]

Now when i enter text inside TextInput and when i click on cancel then the it is clearing the text inside TextInput , Now along with this I want to hide Cancel when is is clicked.

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Dimensions,
    View,
    Animated,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    StyleSheet,

} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../styles/colors';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const PADDING = 16;
const SEARCH_FULL_WIDTH = width - PADDING * 2; //search_width when unfocused
const SEARCH_SHRINK_WIDTH = width - PADDING - 90; //search_width when focused

const AnimatedTouchable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TouchableOpacity);

export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputLength: new Animated.Value(SEARCH_FULL_WIDTH),
            cancelPosition: new Animated.Value(0),
            opacity: new Animated.Value(0),
            searchBarFocused: false,
            text: '',
            showCancel: true
        };
    }


    onFocus = () => {
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(this.state.inputLength, {
                toValue: SEARCH_SHRINK_WIDTH,
                duration: 250
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.cancelPosition, {
                toValue: 16,
                duration: 400
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 250
            }),
        ]).start();
    };

    onBlur = () => {
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(this.state.inputLength, {
                toValue: SEARCH_FULL_WIDTH,
                duration: 250
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.cancelPosition, {
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 250
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 250
            })
        ]).start();
    };

    clearInput = () => {
        this.textInputRef.clear();
        //this.onFocus.bind(this);
        this.setState({
            showCancel: !this.state.showCancel
        });
      }
      _renderCancel() {
        if (this.state.showCancel) {
            return (
                <AnimatedTouchable
                style={[styles.cancelSearch, { right: this.state.cancelPosition }]}
                onPress={(this.clearInput.bind(this))}
            >
                <Animated.Text
                    style={[styles.cancelSearchText, { opacity: this.state.opacity, color: colors.darkBlue }]}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                    value={this.state.text}
                >
                    Cancel
      </Animated.Text>
            </AnimatedTouchable>

            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    render() {
        const { searchBarFocused } = this.state;

        return (
            <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
                <Animated.View
                    style={[
                        styles.search,
                        {
                            width: this.state.inputLength,
                            position: 'absolute',
                            left: 16,
                            alignSelf: 'center'
                        },
                        searchBarFocused === true ? undefined : { justifyContent: 'center' }
                    ]}
                >
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.searchInput}
                        onBlur={this.onBlur}
                        onFocus={this.onFocus}
                        placeholder="Enter condition, primary care, speciality"
                        ref={(ref) => { this.textInputRef = ref; }}
                    />


                </Animated.View>


                <AnimatedTouchable
                    style={[styles.cancelSearch, { right: this.state.cancelPosition }]}
                    onPress={this.clearInput.bind(this)}
                >
                    <Animated.Text
                        style={[styles.cancelSearchText, { opacity: this.state.opacity, color: colors.darkBlue }]}
                        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                        value={this.state.text}
                    >
                        Cancel
          </Animated.Text>
                </AnimatedTouchable>
             {this._renderCancel() }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    searchContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        height: 72,
        borderColor: colors.light_green,
        paddingTop: 100
    },
    search: {
        height: 40,
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: 5,
        borderRadius: 6,
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        borderColor: colors.light_green,
        fontSize: 20,
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
    cancelSearch: {
        position: 'absolute',
        marginHorizontal: 16,
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: colors.darkBlue
    }
});
```

can anyone help me  how to hide Cancel when it is clicked.

when cancel is clicked i want my original TextInput to be like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

set the style to following :

```
style={{ opacity: this.state.isVisible ? 1 : 0 }}
```

and set state `isVisibile` accordingly to make it visible/hidden.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you clearly , can you please tell me where exactly i have to add this style prop

Comment: The element you want to hide, in your case `AnimatedTouchable ` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement the clear text then you can use 
`clearButtonMode`.
[clearButtonMode](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#clearbuttonmode)

Else if you are using state i.e `showCancel` you can use as

```
{showCancel? <CancelButton/> : <View/>}
```